# Removing a point from two spaces being homeomorphis

Tags: general-topology

If we remove a point from each space of two spaces that are homeomorphic, and the homeomorphism sending the two points to each other, I think the two spaces will continue to be homeomorphic, but now both of them being separated or both being connected. Can this be shown in a simple argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $[0,1]\backslash \{0\}$ and $[0,1] \backslash \{1/2\}$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I think you have to add the hypothesis that the homeomorphism sends one point to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any restriction of a continuous function is continuous again, so if $\lambda : \mathbf{X} \to \mathbf{Y}$ is a continuous bijection such that $\lambda^{-1}$ is continuous, too, then for any $x \in \mathbf{X}$ we find that $\lambda|_{\mathbf{X} \setminus \{x\}} : \mathbf{X} \setminus \{x\} \to \mathbf{Y} \setminus \{\lambda(x)\}$ is continuous again, and also a bijection. Likewise, $\lambda^{-1}|_{\mathbf{Y} \setminus \lambda(x)} : {\mathbf{Y} \setminus \lambda(x)}  \to \mathbf{X} \setminus \{x\}$ then is its continuous image.

As being connected (or disconnected) is preserved by homeomorphisms, either both $\mathbf{X} \setminus \{x\}$ and $\mathbf{Y}\setminus \{\lambda(x)\}$ have that property or neither.

Comment: Clearly explained, thanks!